# How do i ignore line breaks in csv file with ruby but keep a pretty source file?

Tags: ruby, csv, erb

I have a csv file with about 30 columns that i would like to output, and would like these to appear in my .csv.erb on different lines, for example:

```
<%= quantity.line_number  %>,
<%= quantity.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>,
<%= quantity.partner_entity_no %>,
<%= quantity.partner_name %>,
```

However when I execute this then my .csv file has line breaks after every ',' I would like to 1) keep each column on separate line in source and 2) have non line breaks in the output .csv file.  How could I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the stdlib [CSV class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) to get csv quoting and escaping semantics right. Or more conveniently, use its [Array#to_csv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/Array.html#method-i-to_csv) helper method.

```
<% require 'csv' %>
...
<%= [ 
      quantity.line_number,
      quantity.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
      quantity.partner_entity_no,
      quantity.partner_name,
    ].to_csv %>
```

Comment: Would you typically have the require 'csv' in the erb html or in the controller in rails? Where would the best place for it be?

Comment: if you've required it in an initializer or controller it should be available in your view.  I just put it there so it was clear it was required.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= [quantity.line_number,
     quantity.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
     quantity.partner_entity_no,
     quantity.partner_name].join(',') %>
```

Comment: good suggestion, but one should probably worry about quoting requirements for fields with embedded separators.